# How we can retrieve real-time database from firebase to Python3 in Jupyter-Notebook (Anaconda)

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Whenever I try to retrieve data from firebase to my .ipynb. It gives me error that there is not such module like firebase_admin. When I installed that module to my conda environment. Again, It says that it is only available for Python2, but I want in Python3. Is there any way please answer:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from firebase import firebase  #firebase data retrieving code #live
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('LINK-TO-DATABASE', None)
result = firebase.get('/user', None)
result # type(result)=dict, JSON formate
```